# PHP variable value is not persisting after a button click

Tags: php

I want to persist a variable value, $a, after clicking on the *Show* button which is not occurring using my code below. I tried with Session and a hidden field, but being a newbie I could might not able to place it properly and hence could not achieve the result.

```
<?php
    $a = $_POST['findSchool'];

    //1. Enter database credentials
    $servername = "****";
    $username = "****";
    $password = "****";
    $dbname = "****";
    $flag = 0;

    // 2. Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    echo '<form id="myNewForm" name="myNewForm" class="form"  method="post" action="">';
    echo '<table class="table table-bordered">';
    echo '<tr scope="col" >
                       <th align="center">SchoolName</th>
                          <th align="center">Details</th>
                      </tr>';
    $sql = "SELECT schName FROM schoolinformation WHERE schName LIKE '%$a%'";
    echo $sql;
    $i = 0;
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while($rowval = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $schName= $rowval['schName'];
        echo '<tr scope="col"><td  align="center">'.$rowval['schName'].'</td>
                           <td align="center"><input type="submit" id="shwData" name="shwData" class="btn" value="Show"/></td>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
    echo '</form>';

    if($schName == '')
    {
        echo "Entry not found";
        $flag = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        //echo $schName;
        $flag = 0;
    }
?>

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['shwData']))
    {
        echo "this is it";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

replace

```
$a = $_POST['findSchool'];
```

with

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['findSchool'])){
 $_SESSION['a'] = $_POST['findSchool'];
}
$a = $_SESSION['a'];
```

and get sure that there is no output before session_start();

Comment: no explanation, SQL injection possible, this could be done also with hidden field.